# Replace js namespaced global variable with js closure

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures, global

I have some **shared code** in a **single-page web application** that is currently using a **"globals" namespace** to store a parameter  as a global variable.

Using a namespace is an improvement over polluting the global "window" object, but it seems like this code is **a good candidate for a closure** to persist the value between invocations. I've messed around with some ideas but can't seem to get the syntax for a closure right.

Here's pseudo-code for the current version. All the code lives inside a "um" namespace. When my shared function is initially called by a new virtual page in my app, I need to store the contents of a JS object called 'extraData'. Subsequent invocations of the function don't have access to 'extraData', so I'm currently storing it in **"um.globals.extraData"** if *underscore.js* determines that the parameter is an object.

```
//***************************
// IMPLEMENTATION SAMPLE
//***************************

// Define namespaces (not showing: um.grid, um.ajax, um.classes, um.constants, etc.)
window.um = window.um || {};

um.globals = um.globals || {}; /* container for namespaced 'global' variables */

um.grid.loadOrUpdate = function (iOffset, isUpdate, extra) {
    var ajaxParams = new um.classes.AjaxParams();
    //-----

    // If 'extra' is an object, store it in a global for subsequent invocations
    if (_.isObject(extra)) {
        // This seems like it could be a closure candidate...
        um.globals.extraData = extra;
    }

    ajaxParams.values = [um.constants.urlPathParams.grid];
    ajaxParams.verb = um.constants.httpVerbs.GET;

    // Use the global variable 'extraData'
    ajaxParams.extraData = um.globals.extraData;

    um.ajax.callMessaging(ajaxParams);
};
```

And here's some pseudo-code for actually invoking the function:

```
//***************************
// INVOCATION SAMPLES
//***************************

// 1st invocation from virtual page 'Alpha'
um.grid.loadOrUpdate(0, false, { "alpha-key": "alpha-value" });

// 2nd invocation from virtual page 'Alpha'
um.grid.loadOrUpdate(1, true); // will re-use the "alpha" object

// 1st invocation from virtual page "Beta'
um.grid.loadOrUpdate(0, false, { "beta-key": "beta-value" });

// 2nd invocation from virtual page 'Beta'
um.grid.loadOrUpdate(1, true); // will re-use the "beta" object
```

How can I kill **um.globals.extraData** and replace this with some kind of **closure** inside of *um.grid.loadOrUpdate*?

**EDIT**

Here's some code from "JavaScript Patterns" that prompted me to ask this question:

```
var setup = function () {
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        return (count += 1);
    }
};

// usage
var next = setup();
next(); // returns 1
next(); // returns 2
next(); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve through closures.  Closures allow you to encapsulate the state of variables within the current scope, which might be handy if you were trying to create various instances of your object, each with their own `extra` state.

You could do this by implementing `loadOrUpdate` in such a way that returns a reference to a function that can be called later.  When said function is called, all the variables within that scope will be *enclosed* and retain the values from when the function was created.

For example:

```
um.grid.loadOrUpdate = function (iOffset, extra) {
    var ajaxParams = new um.classes.AjaxParams();
    //-----

    ajaxParams.values = [um.constants.urlPathParams.grid];
    ajaxParams.verb = um.constants.httpVerbs.GET;

    um.ajax.callMessaging(ajaxParams);

    // Return a function used to update this data later
    return function (newOffset) // Update function
    {
       // From within here, you'll have access to iOffset and extra as they exist at this point
       window.alert("Key: " + extra.key + " - Changing offset from " + iOffset + " to " + newOffset);
       iOffset = newOffset;
    };
};
```

You can then invoke your function like so, keeping in mind it will return a reference to a function:

```
var alpha = um.grid.loadOrUpdate(0, { "key": "alpha-value" });
var beta = um.grid.loadOrUpdate(0, { "key": "beta-value" });
```

When you call `alpha()` or `beta()`, the value of *extra* will be retained through a closure, thus there is no need to keep a global reference to it.

```
alpha(1); // Update from 0 to 1
alpha(2); // Update from 1 to 2
beta(3); // Update from 0 to 3
beta(4); // Update from 3 to 4
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CK6g9/)

However, if you're attempting to keep a single instance of `extra` that all calls to `loadOrUpdate` share, you'd probably be better off using your previous technique and just storing that current value as a property of the function itself, or anywhere else within the scope of that function.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that getting rid of my namespaced 'global' probably isn't a good candidate for a closure inside of 'loadOrUpdate'. As you noted, I only need a single instance of 'loadOrUpdate', and the original implementation works great.  Values in 'um.globals...' are NOT polluting the window namespace, and the name 'globals' makes it clear that any values stored therein are intended to be scoped globally within 'um...' I think this is a case of trying to over-optimize or over-engineer something that's already working just fine.  Globals variables are not intrinsically evil. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of approach what you're after?

```
var ns = {};
(function() {
 var globals;
 ns.func = function(update,opts) {
  if(update)opts=globals;
  else globals=opts;
  console.log(opts);
 }
})();

ns.func(false,"a");
ns.func(true);
ns.func(false,"b");
ns.func(true);
```

Output:

```
a
a
b
b
```

I've scoped the globals variable inside an anonymous function, and made a function declared in that function available on an object in the surrounding (in this case window) scope - so it has access to the 'globals' variable but it's not visible outside it.

Comment: It *seems* like your implementation is still very close to mine in which a global variable outside of 'ns.func' is used to capture 'opts'. I'll update my original question with a closure sample from "Javascript Patterns" that originally made me think that an inline closure was the way to eliminate a global variable.

Comment: Isn't that the same - hiding a variable inside the function scope? The variable 'globals' isn't visible in global scope in my example. The name is a bad one but I kept that to indicate what it was used for in your original example. The variable 'globals' is hidden in the anonymous function's scope.

Comment: Here's a reference in case the terminology was confusing (I just looked it up myself!):  "inner functions referring to local variables of its outer function create closures" http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ ... That's what I've got in my example, a variable referred to by an inner function, scoped in an outer function, invisible in global scope. Similar to Crockford's private variable implementation IIRC.

Comment: I thought that a "proper" closure in JavaScript needed to return a function. Both my original implementation and your version do not return functions, they just store the value in a variable that is hidden from the global "window" scope. I am thinking of some kind of internal function that returns another function, like the 'setup/next' example I added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I think the difference is that in my example the variable `globals` is truly hidden, i.e. inaccessible for anything but the inner function, whereas in your first example the variable is accessible in global scope via `um.globals`, which fits with the definition of a closure I linked to above. But I agree with your last comment on Mike's answer above - what you have is probably fine ;)